# continue downloading when application enter background

Tags: objective-c, ios

I tried ASIHttpRequest to download a file, but when the app enter background, it would stop downloading seconds later, is there any way to download a file completely in background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the download request to be able to continue in background.

```
[self.downloadRequest setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
```

self.downloadRequest is the ASIHTTPRequest, so just replace that with yours, add this line after you init it, and then it will continue in background:]

Comment: Unless the app is one of the special "keeps running in the background" apps, please note that even with this enabled, the download will stop after 10 minutes. A standard iOS app only gets a maximum of 10 minutes to complete a background task.